# Convert percentage change to level in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like the table below. It is the growth rate that I want to change to levels (The Level of column is the data that I desire to have, not the data that is already there). For example, the level is 1 in the first period, 0.9998 ((1-0.0233%)*1) in the second period, 0.9993 ((1-0.0432%)*0.9998) in the third period and so on.

```
    Change      Level
1   -0.0054%    1.0000
2   -0.0233%    0.9998
3   -0.0432%    0.9993
4   -0.0323%    0.9990
5   -0.0390%    0.9986
6   0.1901%     1.0005
7   0.1495%     1.0020
8   0.1444%     1.0035
9   0.1584%     1.0051
10  0.4444%     1.0095
```

My code is something like this: `df1 <- mutate(df, level0 = 1, level1 = (1+change)*lag(level1, 1))`. However, it shows `"object 'level1' not found"`. I guess this is because level1 is not predefined. I wonder what is the best way to do such a calculation.

Comment: Are you trying to compute the level values? I think you already have them in your data

Comment: if you are trying to compute the level values you can do something like:   `c(y<-1,sapply(as.numeric(sub("%","",dat$Change))[-1],function(x)y<<-y*(1+x/100)))` or you can use the `Reduce` function like:   `Reduce(function(x,y)x*(1+y/100),as.numeric(sub("%","",dat$Change))[-1],init=1,accumulate = T)`

Comment: If you use 'dput()' and paste the output here, it'll be easier for us to troubleshoot your problem & provide a tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you ask you are in effect throwing away the first change (as you state that the level should be 1 after the 0.0054% change) then taking the cumulative product of the changes thereafter.

If you are storing the changes as non-numeric data (which is what you show) you need to convert each value to numeric before you can calculate a result from it.

**Test Data**

```
df = read.table(text = "Change
-0.0054%
-0.0233%
-0.0432%
-0.0323%
-0.0390%
0.1901%
0.1495%
0.1444%
0.1584% 
0.4444%", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This just creates a data frame with one column.

**Calculate Level**

To add the Level column, changing your non-numeric data to numeric:

```
getnumber <- function(x){
  as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))
}

df$Level = c(1, cumprod(1+(getnumber(df[[1]][-1]) / 100)))
```

The [-1] in df[[1]][-1] is to remove the first value from the cumulative product as you are not actually using it.

```
> df
     Change     Level
1  -0.0054% 1.0000000
2  -0.0233% 0.9997670
3  -0.0432% 0.9993351
4  -0.0323% 0.9990123
5  -0.0390% 0.9986227
6   0.1901% 1.0005211
7   0.1495% 1.0020169
8   0.1444% 1.0034638
9   0.1584% 1.0050533
10  0.4444% 1.0095197
```